# Strange Wi-Fi "stuttering" (bandwidth drop)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

I have been having Wi-Fi "stuttering" on my PC for months: the bandwidth drops every few seconds from 144Mbps to 48Mpbs, and the download speed to zero. Downloads are not interrupted and there are lag peaks in online games.

See: [Connection speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CANr0.png) / [Normal bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCbdr.png) / [Dropped bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7zjO.png)

The router is a Freebox v6 (2.4GHz, 802.11n) and the receiver a Dootoper "1200-SoataSoa-Wifi Adapter" (-> https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B077X5Y2LT/). I am using Windows 10 Pro.

But my problem does not make much sense :

- Moving the PC does not help;
- The USB dongle works fine when used on another PC;
- The problem is also present when using my mobile phone as a Wi-Fi hotspot (with the phone next to my PC);
- Other devices work fine, even if placed next to my PC (mobile phones, laptops...);
- Wired connections work fine;
- The problem sometimes disappear temporarily.

I have tried everything I could think of (reinstalled drivers and Windows, reset Wi-Fi config, connected the USB dongle to a USB extender, made an offering to the god of IT...).

**Here is what happens in Wireshark:** [Wireshark results when the bandwidth drops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwDj9.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: The presence of TCP DUP packets indicates the use of TCP Fast Retransmission, which occurs upon straight-up packet loss. Does this happen if you use another adapter?

Comment: @JosephA I previously used the PCIe Wifi adapter that came with my motherboard, and I had the same problem.

Comment: This is strange: my first thoughts were the adapter itself, but since the PCIe adapter displays the same symptoms it can't be that -- can you post a screenshot of network devices under device manager? Perhaps it insists on using a single faulty networking driver for any adapter that it uses, but how that persists upon factory reset is beyond me.